# Swift: calling function with variadic arguments from another function with variadic arguments

Tags: swift, variadic-functions, variadic

Scenario:

there's a function which accepts a Variadic parameters with a restriction that there should be at least one argument passed:

```
func sum(_ number: Int, _ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  extraValues.reduce(0, +) + number
}
```

so the result is:

```
sum(1,2,3) // 6
sum(1) // 1
sum(12,3) // 15
sum() // ERROR: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

**This part works just fine.**
*BUT!!*

if I have another similar function:

```
func nestedSum(_ number: Int, _ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  extraValues.reduce(0, +) + number
}
```

SO:
*how to call it from inside another function:*

```
func sum(_ number: Int, _ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  extraValues.reduce(0, +) + number
  // HOW to call nestedSum from inside here ?
}
```

if I do:

```
func sum(_ number: Int, _ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  nestedSum(number, extraValues)
}
```

I'm having:

> Cannot pass array of type 'Int...' as variadic arguments of type 'Int'

I can not even do:

```
func sum(_ number: Int, _ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  nestedSum2(extraValues)
}

func nestedSum2(_ extraValues: Int...) -> Int {
  extraValues.reduce(0, +)
}
```

with same:

> Cannot pass array of type 'Int...' as variadic arguments of type 'Int'